# Using value inside a column to call out which other column should be used in a function call

Tags: r, tidyverse, summarize

I am working on a R script visual that feeds from data in PBI. I have a slicer that is populating a column in a dataframe from a choice of other column headers. This slicer is populating the "letters" column with the column names a through k. I would like to use the value of letters to call a column in a summarize function call. This is because letters will change dynamically as the user changes the slicer. I put a comment where I would like to call this value of letters instead of manually calling a column name of dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)

filtered <-filter(dataset,ScrapRecipeID==SelectedRecipe)
filteredSort<-filtered[order(filtered$YearMonthIndex),]
summarizedRecipe<-filteredSort %>%
    dplyr::group_by(MonthYear,YearMonthIndex)  %>%
    dplyr::summarize(letterMean=mean(a)) %>%  # want to call the value of letters here
    ungroup()
summarizedAll<-dataset %>%
    dplyr::group_by(MonthYear,YearMonthIndex)  %>%
    dplyr::summarize(letterMean2=mean(a)) %>%   # want to call the value of letters here
    ungroup()
```

dput of dataset:

```
dput(head(dataset))
structure(list(a = c(0.00266666666666667, 0.00266666666666667, 
0.00266666666666667, 0.00266666666666667, 0.00266666666666667, 
0.00266666666666667), b = c(2e-04, 2e-04, 2e-04, 2e-04, 2e-04, 
2e-04), c = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), d = c(0.00916666666666667, 0.00916666666666667, 
0.00916666666666667, 0.00916666666666667, 0.00916666666666667, 
0.00916666666666667), e = c(0.148333333333333, 0.148333333333333, 
0.148333333333333, 0.148333333333333, 0.148333333333333, 0.148333333333333
), f = c(0.316666666666667, 0.316666666666667, 0.316666666666667, 
0.316666666666667, 0.316666666666667, 0.316666666666667), g = c(0.0333333333333333, 
0.0333333333333333, 0.0333333333333333, 0.0333333333333333, 0.0333333333333333, 
0.0333333333333333), h = c(0.135, 0.135, 0.135, 0.135, 0.135, 
0.135), SelectedRecipe = c("Recipe 85D", "Recipe 85D", "Recipe 85D", 
"Recipe 85D", "Recipe 85D", "Recipe 85D"), YearMonthIndex = c(24257L, 
24257L, 24257L, 24257L, 24257L, 24257L), MonthYear = c("05-2021", 
"05-2021", "05-2021", "05-2021", "05-2021", "05-2021"), Year = c(12126L, 
12126L, 12126L, 12126L, 12126L, 12126L), ScrapRecipeID = c("", 
"", "", "", "", ""), i = c(0.00193333333333333, 0.00193333333333333, 
0.00193333333333333, 0.00193333333333333, 0.00193333333333333, 
0.00193333333333333), J = c(0.00933333333333333, 0.00933333333333333, 
0.00933333333333333, 0.00933333333333333, 0.00933333333333333, 
0.00933333333333333), k = c(0.0396666666666667, 0.0396666666666667, 
0.0396666666666667, 0.0396666666666667, 0.0396666666666667, 0.0396666666666667
), letters = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: are you trying to create a mean for each variable a through k?

Comment: No, I am using the content of the letters column to determine which column,  between A through K, that I am computing a mean for. That mean is later being passed into ggplot for the visual for context.

Comment: the letters column has values different than you column names the only one that overlaps is 'B'. So in this case B in letters matches column B and you would want that mean correct? Can their be more than one match?

Comment: Nuts, that was an error on my part on renaming values in the dput. It is modified now. Letters will only ever contain the same value in every row; it can be any of the letters between a through k. The actual value is set by the slicer. When the slicer is changed, the value of letters is updated accordingly to be a different column, a-k. I believe the script visual re-computes anytime the slicer is changed basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the unique values in your `letters` column and then get the intersection of the values a-k. You can then pass that vector to `across()` in a `summarize()` to get the mean of those columns that appear in the letter columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
lets <- tolower(unique(df$letters))

coloverlap <- intersect(letters[1:11], lets)
summarizedAll<-df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(MonthYear,YearMonthIndex)  %>%
  dplyr::summarize(across(coloverlap,~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .names =  "letterMean2_{coloverlap}"  )) %>%   
  ungroup()
```

edit if the letter will always be one letter you can use find the unique value and then pass it to mean with the help of rlang:

```
summarizedAll<-df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(MonthYear,YearMonthIndex)  %>%
  dplyr::summarize( lettermean2 = mean(!!rlang::sym(unique(df$letters))) ) %>%   # want to call the value of letters here
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Responded back to you and edited my dput. Apologies if my wording is confusing, I hope I am clarifying correctly.

Comment: I will give it a shot. It looks like it might be overkill since there will only ever be one unique value of letters but I can try it.

Comment: no problem added an update with a simpler example

Comment: I tried the lower solution and got the following error:

Error in `rlang::sym()`:
! Can't convert a character vector to a symbol.

Comment: Nevermind, silly error on my part. I think I got it.